# XSL Counting preceding nodes within a subtree

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

given the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>

<root>

<hi>
<hello-world><greeter> a </greeter><greeter> b </greeter></hello-world>
<hello-world><greeter> c </greeter><greeter> d </greeter></hello-world> 
</hi>

<hi>
<hello-world><greeter> e </greeter><greeter> f </greeter></hello-world>
<hello-world><greeter> g </greeter><greeter> h </greeter></hello-world>
</hi>

</root>
```

I am looping through each **greeter** element within the **hi** subtrees, and I need to output the position of the element within that containing **hi** node

So far I have this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="hi">

<xsl:for-each select="hello-world" >
<xsl:for-each select="greeter" >
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('+',count(ancestor::hi//greeter))" />
</xsl:for-each >
</xsl:for-each >

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However this outputs :

```
+4+4+4+4
+4+4+4+4
```

Whereas I need:

```
+1+2+3+4
+1+2+3+4
```

I have tried **ancestor::hi//greeter**, **ancestor::hi//preceding::greeter** , **ancestor::hi//preceding-sibling::greeter** etc to no avail.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you are making is that you go up to the grandparent level and count the grandchildren from there. That number is always the same, no matter which grandchild is asking.

Try instead something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="root/hi/hello-world/greeter" >
    <xsl:text>+</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number from="hi" level="any"/>
</xsl:for-each >
</xsl:template>
```

Depending on the type of output you want, you'll need to add either a wrapping element or a separator.